# Apply mask to input

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, masking

I need a mask for input that needs to have the format of **dddd-ddd** (Portuguse zip code), I don't feel like importing a library just for this input.

This is what I have right now:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    zip_code: '2770-315'
  },
  computed: {
    mask_zip_code: {
      get: function() {
        return this.zip_code;
      },
      set: function(input) {
        input = input.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, "");
       if(input.length >= 4) {
           input = input.substr(0, 4)+'-'+input.substr(5); // in case people type "-"
        }
        this.zip_code = input;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="mask_zip_code" maxlength="8">
</div>
```

Has you can see the behavior is a little wierd and it allows to type letters as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your snippet to work as you intended it. The `computed` value works but it will not be reflected in the input, instead a method is more appropriate here

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        zip_code: '2770-315'
    },
    methods: {
    mask_zip: function(event) {
        if (event.key && event.key.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) {
           event.preventDefault()
        } else {
            if(this.zip_code.length >= 4) {
                this.zip_code = this.zip_code.substr(0, 4)+'-'+this.zip_code.substr(5); // in case people type "-"
            }
        }
        return this.zip_code;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="mask_zip_code" maxlength="8" @keypress="inputValidation">
  {{mask_zip_code}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, just for the record, I did achieve based on your anwser a more short way: https://jsfiddle.net/g1h9qrfp/1/

Comment: Of course it could've been stripped down, but there could be uses for the computed also. I will update the answer as it is more concise

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `pattern` attribute with a regex:

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<form>
  <input v-model="mask_zip_code" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This should prevent users from submitting the form with anything other than a valid Portuguese zip code.

Comment: Tha's not exactly what I want, that pattern validation will only happen on form submition. I want this in real time, I updated my snipped above, the only problem now is the letters, shouldn't be there when typing

Comment: Then you'll have to use JavaScript for that.  But my answer is still valid, and is one possible way to handle your situation.